# How to use Multi External CDN JavaScript file in Vue CLI Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tried including external JS files in Vue Component by various methods `mounted()`, `created()` but in the end not any solution worked for me. I'm not sure where I'm missing. 
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Here's the code:

```
<template>
  <div id="sketchy"></div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data(){
    return {
    }
  }, mounted() {
      if (document.getElementById('sketchy')) return; // was already loaded
      var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
      scriptTag.src = "https://bootswatch.com/_vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
      scriptTag.id = "sketchy";
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
  },
   mounted() {
      if (document.getElementById('sketchy')) return; // was already loaded
      var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
      scriptTag.src = "https://bootswatch.com/_vendor/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js";
      scriptTag.id = "sketchy";
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
  },
  mounted() {
      if (document.getElementById('sketchy')) return; // was already loaded
      var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
      scriptTag.src = "https://bootswatch.com/_vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
      scriptTag.id = "sketchy";
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
  },
}
</script>


<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: A vue component is basically a JavaScript class. You can't have the same class method (`mounted()`) declared more than once. Instead of `mounted(){ x }, mounted(){ y }, mounted(){ z }` you should only have `mounted(){ x y z }`

Comment: could you please tell me did my answer help?

Comment: Hey @PALLAMOLLASAI Thanks for answering, You made my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following approach. The 3 script files were imported in the **head** tag.

```
mounted:function(){
//   if (document.getElementById('sketchy')) {
//       console.log("loadeddd");
//         return;
//   } // was already loaded
  var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
//   scriptTag.src = "https://bootswatch.com/_vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
  scriptTag.setAttribute('src','https://bootswatch.com/_vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?onload=onLoad')
//   scriptTag.id = "sketchy";
  //scriptTag.setAttribute('id','sketchy');
  scriptTag.async=true;
  scriptTag.defer=true;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
  console.log("scripttag1 createddd");

  var scriptTag1 = document.createElement("script");
  scriptTag1.setAttribute('src','https://bootswatch.com/_vendor/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js?onload=onLoad');
  scriptTag1.async=true;
  scriptTag1.defer=true;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag1);
  console.log("scriptag2 createdd");


  var scriptTag2 = document.createElement("script");
  scriptTag2.setAttribute('src','https://bootswatch.com/_vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js?onload=onLoad');
  scriptTag2.async=true;
  scriptTag2.defer=true;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag2);
  console.log("scriptag3 createdd");

}
```

Comment: Much Thanks! I wanted to confirm is this parameter is mandatory?
```?onload=onLoad```

Comment: Another problem I am facing is when I reload page it doesn't work and I got this error in Console.
```util.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at util.js:55
    at bootstrap.min.js?onload=onLoad:6
    at bootstrap.min.js?onload=onLoad:6```

Comment: I tried without onload=onLoad scripts were loading. But as google suggests it is better to have that.

Comment: Sure, Then it might be problem from my side.

Thanks again!